# Android Studio 3.0 and gradle upgrade - base.apk code is missing while creating apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, dexguard

I tried to upgrade my gradle from 2.3.3 to 3.0.0 in Android Studio 3.0 (stable).

Project builds fine but I get issue while creating/installing APK:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/xxxx Package /data/app/xxxx/base.apk code is missing]

$ adb shell pm uninstall xxxx
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674))
Error while Installing APK
```

If I build standalone APK and install it directly on device/emulator I get that it is malformed/incorrect.

Project is with Kotlin, and DexGuard 8.0.12 which should allow for Kotlin and gradle 3.0.

What is more annoying is fact that issue persist event after reverting to 2.3.3 gradle (Clean & Invalidate, Clean Build, remove /build paths - I tried it all).

Comment: Is there any error occurs when you are creating debug or signed apk ?

Comment: It is while creating debug apk. I found solution - downgrade DexGuard to 8.0.07 (our previous working one) - will update when I have clear idea what was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fix was to update to DexGuard 8.0.17 (not listed yet in release notes).

Comment: i am using the v8.0.22, i am getting the error that mentioned above. Actually this error occur when i want to build without not applied dexguard plug-in. With dexguard plugin it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed in DexGuard 8.1.11.