# Gradle upgrade - base.apk code is missing while creating apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After updating gradle i am getting

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /xxxx Package /data/app/xxxx/base.apk code is missing]
```

i have removed .idea,.gradle,build still getting same error even with clean build it giving same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032757/android-studio-3-0-and-gradle-upgrade-base-apk-code-is-missing-while-creating

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62187743/551744

Comment: @andro How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

run flutter clean command then try to run again, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had success doing "export DEX_PREOPT_DEFAULT=nostripping" before assembleRelease.

Example:

```
export DEX_PREOPT_DEFAULT=nostripping && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score -2):

Again you have to import project newly, I will work.

**Following this steps.**

Copy your existing code in some other folder

open android studio

go to file menu --> New --> Import Project -->Select your newly copied code folder ---> then import.

it getting create project again, then compile it will work